# Aggregating keys with the same value in javascript objects

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects like so:

`[{state: CA, value: 1}, {state: CA, value: 1}, {state: NY, value: 10}]`

I would like the final result to be an object that contains the aggregates of the value for the same states:

`{CA: 2, NY: 10}`

I have this code below to do that:

```js
let arr = [{state: 'CA', value: 1}, {state: 'CA', value: 1}, {state: 'NY', value: 10}];

let finalObj = {};

arr.map(function(item) {
  let state = item.state;
  if (!finalObj[state]) {
      finalObj[state] = item.value;
  }else {
      finalObj[state] += item.value;
  }
});

console.log(finalObj);
```

Is there a better way to do this rather than having those `if` and `else` checks inside of the `map` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I recommend `forEach` instead of `map` if you want a simple loop. However in this case `reduce` is what you really want. I think this is the shortest way to do this I can think of:

```js
const arr = [{state: 'CA', value: 1}, {state: 'CA', value: 1}, {state: 'NY', value: 10}];

const finalObj = arr.reduce((acc, item) => {
  acc[item.state] = (acc[item.state] || 0) + item.value;
  return acc;
}, {});
```

You can just replace the `if/else` with always using an assignment and just doing `(acc[item.state] || 0)` to always get a valid number.

Another option could be to only do the `if` part (which I think is a pretty clean solution):

```js
const arr = [{state: 'CA', value: 1}, {state: 'CA', value: 1}, {state: 'NY', value: 10}];

const finalObj = arr.reduce((acc, item) => {
  if(!acc[item.state]) {
    acc[item.state] = 0;
  }
  acc[item.state] += item.value;
  return acc;
}, {});
```